# Yammer embed events don't fire

Tags: javascript, yammer

```
yam.on('/embed/loggedIn', logged);
function logged() {
    console.log("I'm logged");
}
```

// This is not working :-/ 
Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: Can you try this again, it should be OK now.